# How to set up two different log levels for two appenders via logback.xml in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I have some problem with logback.xml configuration. I want that console-appender write into console only info events and file-appender write into file  with debug level.My current config looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="applogs"/>

    <appender name="FILE_DAILY" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/News_App_MRM.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_DAILY"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a logger like this

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

With this, all logs coming from org.hibernate will be logged on a INFO level.

You can then specify an appender for each logger.